# Fit WPF Usercontrol height to its contents

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.5

I have below WPF usercontrol. It contains a grid as a root. Grid consists of a single row and 4 columns. In the second column there is a label which is changing its height due to more text is added to it. I have seen that as a result of it, the grid height is changing as well, which is what I want but the usercontrol height isn't. So how to fit usercontrol height to its content height (in this case grid height) ?

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:myConverters"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="40" d:DesignWidth="500">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- Converters -->
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
            <conv:InvertBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InvertBoolToVisibility" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Column="0" 
               Width="24"
               Height="24"
               Margin="8"
               Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolToVisibility}}"
               Source="{Binding Path=Icon}"/>
        
        <Label Grid.Column="1"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               MaxWidth="700"
               Width="auto"
               Height="Auto"
               Margin="5"
               Foreground="{Binding Path=ForegroundColor}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Height="auto" 
                       Width="auto" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </Label>

        <Button Grid.Column="2"
                Width="80"
                Height="28"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                Margin="5,5,30,5"
                Padding="5"
                Content="Clear"
                Foreground="Red"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
                Click="ButtonClear_Click"/>
        
        <Image Grid.Column="3"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               MinWidth="36"
               Width="36"
               Height="36"
               Margin="8,2"
               Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolToVisibility}}"
               Source="{Binding Path=Logo}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Remove d:DesignHeight="40"

Comment: I think the possibility to resize depends on what type of container holds the user control. If the container is auto resizing then the user control auto resize too

Answer (score 0):

Set VerticalAlignment="Center" and HorizontalAlignment="Center" of UC 
In such case UC will calculate size based on content.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rodri.
You could refer to the  following code to set the height of the UserControl to change with the height of its content.

```
 UserControl:
  <UserControl x:Class="LabelTextBox.UserControl1"
         xmlns=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation
         xmlns:x=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml
         xmlns:mc=http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006 
         xmlns:d=http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LabelTextBox"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="{Binding ElementName=grid ,Path=ActualHeight}" d:DesignWidth="{Binding ElementName=grid,Path=ActualWidth}">
<Grid x:Name="grid"  Background="Green" Height="{Binding ElementName=label,Path=ActualHeight}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" x:Name="label"  MaxWidth="200" Background="red"   >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Label>
    <Button Grid.Column="2"
            Width="80"
            Height="28"
            Content="Remove All"
            Foreground="Red"    Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyText,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="3" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    private string myText = "helo";

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string MyText
    {
        get { return myText; }
        set
        {
            myText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
Window:

   <Grid>
    <local:UserControl1 />

</Grid>
```